# Get text from ".txt" file and save it in String variable dart

Tags: string, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I have a ".txt" file called "bio.txt" inside the Document folder of my application.
I want to read its content and store it inside a String variable.
My problem is that the "reading action" is a "Future" function and I have some troubles to save its value in a "String".

I read the file with :

```dart
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> _localFile(String name) async {
  final path = await _localPath;
  return File('$path/$name');
}

Future<String> _read(String filename) async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile(filename);

    // Read the file.
    return await file.readAsString();
  } catch (e) {
    // If encountering an error, return 0.
    return "Can't read";
  }
}
```

And I would like to save it with :

```dart
String _bio = _read("bio.txt").then((value) => String);
```

Do you know why this solution isn't working?
Any suggestion?

Comment: You can read more about async/futures here at https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `then` of Futures won't return a value, it should be like this,

```dart
var _bio;

_read("bio.txt").then((value) {
  _bio = value;
});
```

or by making the context `_bio` is in to an asynchronous one,

```dart
var _bio = await _read("bio.txt");
```

Comment: I Don't want to store values inside a "var" but inside a "String".

Comment: @MichealRoss Then use `String _bio` in the first version, or just use the second version (in which case type inference will make `_bio` a `String`).

Comment: @MichealRoss I opt-out the type for `_bio` because the read function already has a return type that makes `_bio` a `String`. Dart, not like Java, only use types for checking and types are not passed down to compilation. Using fewer types without losing the type safety is better in Dart.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a then block or use the async/await

```
_read ('file.txt').then((value){
bio = value;
 });
```

Or:

`bio = await _read ('file.txt');`

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution :

```
String _myRead( String filename){
 var _bio;

 _read("bio.txt").then((String) {
   _bio = String;
 });
 return _bio;
}
String _bio=_myRead("bio.txt");
```